# SSL cert for secure.domain.net - when I don't own www.domain.net

Tags: security, http, ssl, https

I am writing an application for a business who have an existing website.

I would like the application to be behind SSL, and on my server - so completely separate from the existing business's website.

So for example, they are: http://www.dogsittingservices.net - pointing to their website, on their host.

I would like to be able to have https://secure.dogsittingservices.net - pointing to the web application sitting on my server.

Is this possible at all?  If so, who would have to order the SSL cert - the current business for www.dogsittingservices.net - or me?  How could I order a certificate for a domain I don't own?  That's my dilema.

Thank you for any guidance/advice,

Mark

**UPDATE following @EJP answer**

So are these the steps I would need to take:

1. The business that has the website would setup in their DNS:
   secure.dogsittingservices.net
2. They would then point that DNS to the IP address of my server
3. I would then setup a website on my server with the name: secure.dogsittingservices.net
4. I would then generate a CSR for it from my server
5. I'd then give the CSR to the business that I'm doing the work for
6. The business would then have to use the CSR I generated from my server, to order the SSL
7. They would then send me the SSL key/code to me to apply to my server

Is that how this is normally achieved?

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have to obtain their own SSL certificate. That's the whole point of them, that they definitely identify the business they are issued to.

Comment: If you can generate the CSR you must also have the private key, so you can submit the CSR yourself, but the business has to respond appropriately to the offline queries generated by the CA to validate the request.

Comment: Thanks - so would the other steps be correct - other than I can generate the CSR myself, and assuming the admin contact for the domain responds, I'll get the cert, and install it - with regards to them setting up DNS for my IP etc - is that all correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can also have one SSL certificate with multiple site-use, as an option. Read up more on [SAN certificates](http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm) as it may become relevant to your solution. This would allow you to share the certificate and suit both hostnames. You can also do a [wildcard certificate](http://www.thawte.com/ssl/wildcard-ssl-certificates/index.html) as well if you may have more hostnames for that domain in the future.